# How can I convert a list of objects to csv?

Tags: c#, linq, list, csv, generics

If I have a list of objects called "Car":

```
public class Car
{
     public string Name;
     public int Year;
     public string Model;
}
```

How do I convert a list of objects, e.g. List<Car> to a csv?

Comment: Are you able to convert it?  Which one did you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to convert a list of objects to csv with each object values in a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683161/fastest-way-to-convert-a-list-of-objects-to-csv-with-each-object-values-in-a-new)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) Library
2. Text OleDb Provider
3. Manual via String concatenation according to [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)
4. Third party library, for example [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) can do it without any friction from you. And it is *very* fast.

Comment: +1 for the link to the RFC! There's also a nice reference on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 9):

add the following method to Car:

```
String Escape(String s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool needQuotes = false;
    foreach (char c in s.ToArray())
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '"': sb.Append("\\\""); needQuotes = true; break;
            case ' ': sb.Append(" "); needQuotes = true; break;
            case ',': sb.Append(","); needQuotes = true; break;
            case '\t': sb.Append("\\t"); needQuotes = true; break;
            case '\n': sb.Append("\\n"); needQuotes = true; break;
            default: sb.Append(c); break;
        }
    }
    if (needQuotes)
        return "\"" + sb.ToString() + "\"";
    else
        return sb.ToString();
}

public void SerializeAsCsv(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Write(Escape(Name));
    stream.Write(",");
    stream.Write(Year.ToString());
    stream.Write(",");
    stream.Write(Escape(Model));
    stream.Write("\n");
}
```

Now you can serialize the whole list:

```
foreach (Car car in list)
{
    car.SerializeAsCsv(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Look at the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) library.

From the site:

`The FileHelpers are a free and easy to use  .NET library to import/export  data from fixed length or delimited records in files, strings or streams.`

This will make sure that all kinds of gotchas in line termination, escaping and such are handled correctly, as per [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a solution for this, but none of the answers I found satisfied my drive for simplicity.  I realised I had the answer already with my auto CRUD code.  I repurposed it and came up with the following code:

```
using System.Reflection;
    /// <summary>
    /// Using a bit of reflection to build up the strings.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToCsvHeader(this object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                       BindingFlags.Public |
                                       BindingFlags.Instance);

        string result = string.Empty;
        Array.ForEach(properties, prop =>
        {
            result += prop.Name + ",";
        });

        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1) : result);
    }

    public static string ToCsvRow(this object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                       BindingFlags.Public |
                                       BindingFlags.Instance);

        string result = string.Empty;
        Array.ForEach(properties, prop =>
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            var propertyType = prop.PropertyType.FullName;
            if (propertyType == "System.String")
            {
                // wrap value incase of commas
                value = "\"" + value + "\"";
            }

            result += value + ",";

        });

        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1) : result);
    }
```

This would add an extension method on to every object.  Usage like this:

```
var burgers = new List<Cheeseburger>();
var output = burgers.ToCsvHeader();
output += Environment.NewLine;

burgers.ForEach(burger =>
{
    output += burger.ToCsvRow();
    output += Environment.NewLine;
});
var path = "[where ever you want]";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, output);
```

There is probably a better way to write these two methods above, but this works perfectly for my situation.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply override the ToString method or create a ToCSVRow() method as such

```
    public String ToCSVRow()
    {
        return Name + "," + Year.ToString() + "," + Model;
    }
```

And then just do something like this where needed.

```
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Wherever\yourfilename.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var item in yourlist)
            {
                file.WriteLine(item.ToCSVRow());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting together comma-separated values I always like to point at the much underrated `string.Join(string separator, string[] elements)` static method, but if there are helper libraries out there, that's probably better stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement some addtional serialzation behaviors as per this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx).  If you want to get fancy, you can create a setting in your projects properties.  This setting would determine if your class used csv or default serialialization.  You'd then access it through the techniques shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingsreader.aspx).  Consider using a static constructor to read appsettings and make a boolean value accessable to your serialization code.  Vlads' code looks great, just plug it in to your code.  Also you can consider other, maybe more desirable ways to change your serialzation behavior.

Or Create an interface called 'SerializeAsCSV' and use it kind of like this:

// Partial Contents of MyCoolClass.csv:

```
   public class MyCoolClass : ISerializeAsCSV, IDisposable
   {

      protected static bool serializesToCSV = false;


      static MyCoolClass()
      {
         serializesToCSV = 
            (typeof(MyCoolClass).GetInterface("GrooveySoft.Shared.Interfaces.ISerializeAsCSV") == null)
            ? false
            : true;

      }


      public MyCoolClass(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
      {
        // your stuff here
      }

      public void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
      {
         // your stuff here
      }

    }
```

// contents of ISerializeAsCSV.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace GrooveySoft.Shared.Interfaces
{
   /// <summary>
   /// indicates that implementor will serialize to csv format
   /// </summary>
   public interface ISerializeAsCSV : ISerializable
   {
   }
}
```

This should get your started . . . I haven't compiled and tested this . . but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Linq to CSV](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv), a package available from NuGet. See [Combine contents of two files using LINQ to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845838) for example usage.