# C# writeline properly show leading zeros save as csv

Tags: c#, csv, text

Got a problem in properly handling leading zeros in csv, already tried adding `'` before the string value but in csv file it shows `'StringValue`

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZTmI.jpg)

Already tried `\t` it works but when i try to open it with notepad it shows a tab.

Is there other way I can solve this issue? My main purpose is that when it is open through csv file the `'` must not show and when I open it with text editor it will not tab.

This is my current code

```
foreach (var i in TransmittedDataBLL.Instance.GetDepEdTextFile(data))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(
                "'" + i.Region.ToString() + ",'" + i.Division.ToString() + ",'" + i.Station.ToString() + ",'" + i.EmployeeNumber.ToString()
                + "," + i.FirstName.ToString() + "," + i.MiddleInitial.ToString() + "," + i.LastName.ToString() + "," + i.Appelation.ToString()
                + ",'" + i.DednCode.ToString() + "," + i.DednSubCode.ToString() + ",'" + i.EffectDate.ToString() + ",'" + i.TermDate.ToString()
                + ",'" + i.AmountStr.ToString() + ",'" + i.LoanAmountStr.ToString() + ",'" + i.InterestAmountStr.ToString() + ",'" + i.OtherChargesStr.ToString()
                + "," + i.BillingType.ToString() + "," + i.UpdateCode.ToString()
                );
        }
```

Updated Code:

```
writer.WriteLine("'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}'", i.Region.ToString(), i.Division.ToString(), i.Station.ToString(), i.EmployeeNumber.ToString());
```

Updated Code: Same issue, leading zeros not showing

```
writer.WriteLine("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"", i.Region.ToString(), i.Division.ToString(), i.Station.ToString(), i.EmployeeNumber.ToString());
```

This the data from my query

[SAMPLE RAW DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeHyZ.jpg)

Full code:

```
private void CreateTextFile(string regioncode, string branchcode)
{
    string sFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("mmddyyyy") + ".csv";
    string Serverpath=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"].ToString() + "\\DepEdReports\\";

    TransmittedData data = new TransmittedData();
    data.Region = regioncode.Trim();
    data.BranchCode = branchcode.Trim();

    if (!Directory.Exists(Serverpath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Serverpath);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Serverpath + sFileName + ".csv"))//Server.MapPath("TextFiles/" + sFileName + ".txt")))
    {
        foreach (var i in TransmittedDataBLL.Instance.GetDepEdTextFile(data))
        {
            //writer.WriteLine(
            //    i.Region + "," + i.Division + "," + i.Station + "," + i.EmployeeNumber
            //    + "," + i.FirstName + "," + i.MiddleInitial + "," + i.LastName + "," + i.Appelation
            //    + "," + i.DednCode + "," + i.DednSubCode + "," + i.EffectDate + "," + i.TermDate
            //    + "," + i.AmountStr + "," + i.LoanAmountStr + "," + i.InterestAmountStr + "," + i.OtherChargesStr
            //    + "," + i.BillingType + "," + i.UpdateCode
            //    );
            //writer.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"", i.Region, i.Division, i.Station, i.EmployeeNumber));

            writer.WriteLine(GetCSV(i));

        }
    }

    FileStream fs = null;
    //fs = File.Open(Server.MapPath("TextFiles/" + sFileName + ".txt"), FileMode.Open);
    fs = File.Open(Serverpath + sFileName + ".csv", FileMode.Open);
    byte[] fbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(fbyte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    fs.Close();

    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(fbyte);
    Response.End();

}

private string GetCSV(TransmittedData i)
{
    string[] list = new string[]
    {
        i.Region.ToString(),
        i.Division.ToString(),
        i.Station.ToString(),
        i.EmployeeNumber.ToString(),
        i.FirstName,
        i.MiddleInitial,
        i.LastName,
        i.Appelation.ToString(),
        i.DednCode.ToString(),
        i.DednSubCode.ToString(),
        i.EffectDate.ToString(),
        i.TermDate.ToString(),
        i.AmountStr,
        i.LoanAmountStr,
        i.InterestAmountStr,
        i.OtherChargesStr,
        i.BillingType.ToString(),
        i.UpdateCode.ToString()
    };

    string csvLine = "\"" + string.Join(@"", "", list) + "\"";
    return csvLine;
}
```

Comment: the values that youre writing, are they integer types that youre trying to write?

Comment: @SimonPrice, no. they are all strings

Comment: just out of curiosity, how come your numbers are string type and not int?

Comment: @SimonPrice because the given numbers from the report table has leading zeros

Comment: that makes sense to me now then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add another single quote at the end of each field for example

```
   writer.WriteLine("=\"" + i.Region.ToString() + "\",=\"" + i.Division.ToString() + "\",=\""
```

you can use `string.Format` and give the fields using parameters, example

```
writer.WriteLine(string.Format("=\"{0}\",=\"{1}\"", i.Region,i.Division));
```

Note that many alternatives available to convert generic list to CSV rather than doing it by your own code.

[How can I convert a list of objects to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306667/how-can-i-convert-a-list-of-objects-to-csv)

[Fastest way to convert a list of objects to csv with each object values in a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683161/fastest-way-to-convert-a-list-of-objects-to-csv-with-each-object-values-in-a-new)

Comment: Tried your solution but still gives me the same problem https://postimg.org/image/5afizimnf/ check link thanks

Comment: tried but leading zeros not showing, updated my code. thanks

Comment: in your input strings is there leading zeros ?

Comment: use `=\"` before the value and at end add only `\"`, check my updated code

Comment: @Angelo11292 Finally! :) I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Standardization you should put all your values inside double quotes or do not use quotes at all.

```
        foreach( var i in TransmittedDataBLL.Instance.GetDepEdTextFile( data ) )
        {
            writer.WriteLine( GetCSV( i ) );
        }
    }

    protected string GetCSV( TransmittedData i )
    {
        string[] list = new string[]
        {
            i.Region.ToString(),
            i.Division.ToString(),
            i.Station.ToString(),
            i.EmployeeNumber.ToString(),
            i.FirstName,
            i.MiddleInitial,
            i.LastName,
            i.Appelation.ToString(),
            i.DednCode.ToString(),
            i.DednSubCode.ToString(),
            i.EffectDate.ToString(),
            i.TermDate.ToString(),
            i.AmountStr,
            i.LoanAmountStr,
            i.InterestAmountStr,
            i.OtherChargesStr,
            i.BillingType.ToString(),
            i.UpdateCode.ToString()
        };

        string csvLine = "\"" + string.Join( "\",\"", list ) + "\"";
        return csvLine;
    }
```

If all your values are strings (like you mentioned above) you can omit the `.ToString()` for better readibillity.

If you want leading zeros to be shown you can use `string.PadLeft()` on the corresponding line:

```
i.Region.ToString().PadLeft( 8, '0' ) //make region to a total length of 8 and fills up with zeroes on the left side
```

in case some of your values are not strings but integers you can simply use `.ToString( "D8" )`

Comment: tried your solution sir but gives error https://postimg.org/image/pvquwas59/ check link thanks

Comment: got error Error 8 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Answer (score 1):

Putting a tab space before solves the issue:

`"\t" + field`